# Accessing custom property of lists of site definition in default.aspx page

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, site-definition, list-definition

I am working on Sharepoint. I am creating a site definition that is having a list using that I am insert so many properties inside the list. I am done with the creation part. Now I have to display the properties of the list in default.aspx page of Site definition. I have defined the properties of the list inside the schema.xml file in List Definition.
I have used ProjectProperty, ListProperty, ListItemProperty and even FieldValue. But I am not able to fetch that property values.

Please suggest me how to go with this.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some wired answers for this on net. They say that default.aspx page of site definition is not of Field Type so we can't access custom property in this page directly. So what I did is I created a XsltListViewWebPart using a XSLT and using that I am able to fetch the custom fields of my list.

Hope this will work for others as well.